# How to get Google Project id - not project name

Tags: gcloud

I can get the project name with:

Update: found the solution here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/bash-hacks-gcloud-kubectl-jq-etc-c2ff351d9c3b

```
gcloud config get-value project
```

But I need the project id in a script to be able to push docker image to registry.

Note: I kn ow I can get the id from the browser, but I need it in a script.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the shout out ;-) Many times the project name and the project ID are synonymous. `gcloud config get-value project` is the project ID. If you need the project number, you can `gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format="value(projectId)"`. And, `gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format="value(name)"`. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The command line you have works correctly for getting the project id. In general for projects there is:

id: A globally unique alphanumeric string that identifies a project. You can choose this when creating a project

number: A random number that gets generated and assigned to a project when you create it.

name: This is non-unique free from text to describe the project. This cannot actually be used to identify a project, but is rather just for display purposes.

`gcloud` works in terms of project id (in both the config and in flags you pass to commands) so this is what you want.