# How to get a create table query that was used to generate a table in a dataset in google's big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to get a create table query that was used to generate a table in a dataset in google's big query? I am trying to find it but unable to find that information by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Below query gives away the `create` table query from information_schema

```
SELECT distinct job_type, statement_type,query,state,start_time
FROM `YOUR_PROJECT_ID`.`region-YOUR_REGION`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE statement_type = 'CREATE_TABLE'
order by start_time desc
```

See documentation here to run the queryto find create table by `USER, FOLDER and ORGANIZATIO`N level too

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs

Hope this helped!

Comment: I have one more question. I do not have access to the google console  and I can execute sql queries via rest call. One of my select quries has a from clause like `from <numeric value>.str1.str2`. Based on your response, what should my from look like? I tried few combos but not working

Comment: Which api are you using to make this call? looking are your use case, I think best possible way would be via cloud logging - you can just type in the table name in the search bar and that should give you all the hits against the table name

Comment: I am making a query call but over an api. I do not have access to the console. This is a wrapper api internal to company but takes query as a json key and string as a json value. But my Q is simply given the above example I gave in my comment, how do i find `YOUR_PROJECT_ID` ? Is it the numeric value or str1 or str2 from my from clause eample?

Comment: Hi @curiousengineer, can you take a look at this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182917/how-to-get-google-project-id-not-project-name) and [link2](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7014113?hl=en#:~:text=To%20locate%20your%20project%20ID,a%20member%20of%20are%20displayed.) ?